# Ĉu ekzistas esprimo por "head or tail" / "pile ou face" / "Kopf oder Zahl"

Tags: translation, expression

Ĉu ekzistas esprimo por demandi al homo pri veto, kiu el la du flankoj de ordinara monero estas supera post ĵeto?

Temas fakte pri nomado de la du flankoj de monero, kiuj kutime montras emblemon (ekz. de famulo) kaj nombron indikantan la monvaloron de la monero.

En diversaj lingvoj mi trovis jenajn esprimojn (kun mia proksimuma traduko):

- germane: *Kopf oder Zahl* (kapo / nombro)
- france: *Pile ou face* (Stako / vizaĝo)
- itale: *testa o croce* (kapo / kruco)
- hispane: *cara o cruz* (vizaĝo / kruco)
- angle: *Head or tail* (kapo / fino, figure)

La traduko "Emblemo aŭ nombro" estus mia intuicia provo, sed mi ŝatus scii, ĉu ekzistas iu konata esprimo por tio, kiun mi ĝis nun ne konis.

Comment: Mi ne konas esprimon por tio, sed ĉiuokaze en via (laŭ mi tute taŭga) traduko anstataŭ _nombro_ devus miaopinie esti _cifero_, ĉar temas pri la simbolo, ne ties valoro.

Comment: Se estas tie ekzemple la nombro 20, ĉu tiam oni povas paroli pri *cifero* ? ĉu devus esti *ciferoj* ? Via respondo cetere pensigis min pri "Simbolo au valoro", eble ankau tauga esprimo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laŭ ReVo:

> speso ... havis sur la **averso** la profilon de Zamenhof kaj sur la
>   **reverso** blazonon; reverso de monero, ŝtofo, paĝo, ktp.

Laŭ PIV:

> - **fronto** ➞ antaŭa parto de objekto: fronto de monero, medalo (la flanko, sur kiu estas prezentita vizaĝo)
> - **dorso** ➞ malantaŭa parto de objekto

Laŭ Granda Vortaro hispana-esperanta:

> - ludi je fronto aŭ dorso
> - ludi je averso aŭ reverso
> - decidi laŭ fronto aŭ dorso per mon-ĵeto.

Comment: Interese, dankon. Tamen, la aserto, ke la vizaĝo estas sur la fronto estas iam arbitra lau mi, mi ne certas, kiom da Esperantistoj konscias pri tio.

Comment: Mi konsentas ke tio povas esti arbitra. Ofte oni interkonsentas pri kio estas la fronto kaj kio la dorso antaŭ ol ĵeti la moneron kaj montras ambaŭ flankojn dirante "jen la fronto kaj jen la dorso". Por mi estas pli logike diri _fronto_ ol diri _vizaĝo_, des pli kiam la monero tute ne havas ajnan vizaĝon en ties flankoj.

Answer (score 2):

Mi ĉiam diras *averso* kaj *malaverso*.

Aliaj eblaj terminoj estas:

- kapo aŭ vosto
- bildo aŭ blazono
- fronto aŭ dorso
- averso aŭ reverso.

Answer (score 1):

fronto aŭ pugo...  1 aŭ 0...  Jes aŭ Ne..  Decidu la ludantoj, mi suspektas en ili sufiĉan cerbon por kompreni tiun Kontraŭon inter tio kaj maltio!